# Testing a boolean method that checks properties of a triangle

Tags: java, if-statement

I have been searching for over an hour for something that should have been an easy assignment. 
Please help me out, i'll give you all my code but the problem is at the bottom part. The part with the method.

This is an EDIT. I already changed my calculation (i was using ^ instead of (a*a) but it didn't solve everything)

**My code:**

```
package domein;

public class Driehoek
{
    //attributen
    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int c;


    //constructors

    public Driehoek(int a , int b , int c)
    {
        this.setA(a);
        this.setB(b);
        this.setC(c);

    }

    //setters
    public void setA (int a)
    {
        if (a > 0)
            this.a = a;
        else
            this.a = 1;

    }

    public void setB (int b)
    {
        this.b = (b > 0 ? b : 1);
    }

    public void setC (int c)
    {
        this.c = (b > 0 ? b : 1);
    }  

    //getters
    public int getA()
    {
        return a;
    }

    public int getB()
    {
        return b;
    }

    public int getC()
    {
        return c;
    }

    //methode
    public boolean isRechthoekigeDriehoek(int a, int b, int c);

        if((a * a) + (b * b) == (c * c)) {

                 return true;
        }
        else 
        {
                 return false;
        } 

}
```

**Test package:**

```
package domein;

import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class DriehoekTest
{
private Driehoek driehoek1,driehoek2,driehoek3,driehoek4;

@Before
public void before()
{
    driehoek1 = new Driehoek(0,2,3);
    driehoek2 = new Driehoek(2,0,3);
    driehoek3= new Driehoek(2,3,0);
    driehoek4= new Driehoek(3,4,5);
}

@Test
public void controleerDriehoekZijdeAWordt1BijCreatie()
{
    Assert.assertEquals(1, driehoek1.getA());
}

@Test
public void controleerDriehoekZijdeBWordt1BijCreatie()
{
    Assert.assertEquals(1, driehoek2.getB());
}

@Test
public void controleerDriehoekZijdeCWordt1BijCreatie()
{
    Assert.assertEquals(1, driehoek3.getC());
}

@Test
public void controleerRechthoekigeDriehoek()
{
    Assert.assertEquals(true, driehoek4.isRechthoekigeDriehoek());
}

@Test
public void controleerGeenRechthoekigeDriehoek()
{
    Assert.assertEquals(false, driehoek2.isRechthoekigeDriehoek());
}

}
```

Comment: So you want us to do this for you? Because we are experienced and you are not? How do you think we became experienced?

Comment: Is there a typo in your `setC` method?

Comment: J.P. was right! there was a type in my setC method. thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

This,

```
if(a^2 + b^2 = c^2) {
```

is using bitwise-xor, not exponentiation (Java doesn't have an exponentiation operator). Also, `=` is assignment (not equality testing). The easiest fix is probably something like,

```
if ((a*a) + (b*b) == (c*c)) {
```

Comment: small addition: you can do: return (a * a) + (b * b) == (c * c); that saves some space and does the same thing :)

Comment: Yes, i had to add spaces, since the comment system apperantly transforms "a * a" without spaces to: (a * a) + (b * b) == (c * c)...edit: ok now it does it correctly.. i dont know what happend :P

Answer (score 3):

You misunderstand the `^` operator: it is a bitwise XOR in Java, not a power operator.

To get the code that determines if you are looking at the right triangle use `a*a` or `Math.pow(a, 2)`.

Note that your algorithm will not find the correct answer

- **When some of the lengths are negative** - squaring a negative number produces a positive result, so `(-3, 4, 5)` would produce `true`
- **When the longest side is not the last one on the list** - a combination of `(5, 4, 3)` defines a right triangle, but your `isRechthoekigeDriehoek` method would return `false`.